# Converting HTML to PDF with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

I'm trying to convert an HTML file to PDF. The whole idea is to create a pdf with many pages, filling the first one with the HTML file contents. Currently I'm trying to do just that, and the code is:

```
  #include "qprinterexample.h"
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>
    #include <QTextDocument>
    #include <QTextStream>
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QPrinter>
    #include <QDir>

   int print(){
    const int highQualityDPI = 300;
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    QFile  htmlFile ("ejemplo.htm");
    if (!htmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        return -1;
    }

    QString htmlContent;
    QTextStream in(&htmlFile);
    in >> htmlContent;

    QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument();
    document->setHtml(htmlContent);

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);

    printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");

    document->print(&printer);
    delete document;
    return 0;
}

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QPrinterExample w;
        if(print()<0) return -1;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

But when I check the output PDF, it's an empty page, just with the page number 1 at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I have noticed that when using QTextStream, it only gets "

Comment: A sample from Qt Wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/Exporting_a_document_to_PDF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
 htmlContent=in.readAll();
```

Instead of

```
 in >> htmlContent;
```

This should work!

Comment: Sure, that was stupid from me... Anyway it still doesn't work. I have corrected the code at the Q