# QtWidget Convert HTML to PDF

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

The code below is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697228/converting-html-to-pdf-with-qt).

But I still can't get it to work. From basic debugging I think there is something wrong with passing the filenames to the function. There is no reaction at all when I clicked on the "Print as PDF" button.

The main code is as below. If you would like to see further, feel free to ask them from me. Thanks.

Part of main.cpp

```
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //Get filename for all documents
    QString filename = get_filename(Var_STR);
    QString txt = txt_filename(filename);
    QString csv = csv_filename(filename);
    QString html = html_filename(filename);

    //Print report in .txt, .csv and .html accordingly
    heading(txt, csv, html, Var_STR, Var_INT[6], Var_INT[16], Var_INT[17]);
    pp_prerinse(txt, csv, html, Var_INT[18], Var_INT[19], Var_INT[20], Var_INT[21], Var_INT[22], Var_INT[23], Var_INT[24], Var_INT[25], Var_INT[26], Var_REAL[11], Var_INT[30], Var_INT[31], Var_INT[32]);
    pp_wash(txt, csv, html, Var_STR, Var_INT[33], Var_INT[34], Var_INT[35], Var_INT[36], Var_INT[37], Var_INT[38], Var_REAL[23], Var_INT[41], Var_INT[42], Var_INT[43], Var_REAL[28], Var_INT[47], Var_INT[48], Var_INT[49], Var_INT[50], Var_INT[51], Var_INT[52], Var_INT[53], Var_INT[54], Var_INT[55], Var_REAL[40]);
    pp_rinse(txt, csv, html, Var_INT[59], Var_INT[60], Var_INT[61], Var_INT[62], Var_INT[63], Var_INT[64], Var_INT[65], Var_INT[66], Var_INT[67], Var_INT[68], Var_INT[69], Var_INT[70], Var_INT[71], Var_INT[72], Var_INT[73], Var_INT[74], Var_INT[75], Var_INT[76], Var_INT[77], Var_REAL[61]);
    phase_prerinse(txt, csv, html, Var_STR, Var_REAL[64], Var_REAL[67], Var_REAL[70]);
    wash(txt, csv, html, Var_STR, Var_REAL[73], Var_REAL[75], Var_REAL[77], Var_REAL[79], Var_REAL[81], Var_REAL[83], Var_REAL[85], Var_REAL[87], Var_REAL[89], Var_REAL[91], Var_REAL[94], Var_REAL[97]);
    rinse(txt, csv, html, Var_INT[129], Var_STR);
    basin_flush(txt, csv, html, Var_STR);
    alarms_code(txt, csv, html, Var_REAL[100], Var_REAL[103], Var_REAL[106]);
    tail(txt, csv, html);

    //Report preview UI and convert .html to .pdf
    QDir htmlpath = QFileInfo(html).absoluteDir();
    MainWindow mainWindow((htmlpath.absolutePath())+"/"+html, filename);
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle("Print Preview");
    mainWindow.showMaximized();
    return app.exec();
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>
#include "windows.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include "qt_windows.h"
#include "qwindowdefs_win.h"
#include <ShellAPI.h>
namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
    class QPrinter;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QString previewfile = "", QString file = "", QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void buttonPrint(QString filepath);
    void buttonCancel();

private:
    QWebView *m_pWebView; //Preview of the report layout
    QPushButton *m_button; //Print button
    QPushButton *n_button; //Cancel button
    QString printfile;
    QString filepath;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QString previewfile, QString file, QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    //Open html version of report
    m_pWebView = new QWebView(this);

    //Set position and size
    m_pWebView->setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 735);
    m_pWebView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(previewfile));

    //Create "print" button
    m_button = new QPushButton("Print as PDF", this);

    //Set location of button
    m_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(1100, 150), QSize(75, 23)));

    //Print button action
    connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonPrint(file)));

    n_button = new QPushButton("Cancel", this);

    n_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(1100, 179), QSize(75, 23)));

    connect(n_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonCancel()));
}

void MainWindow::buttonPrint(QString filepath)
{
    QFile htmlfile(filepath+".html");
    if(htmlfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QString htmlContent;
        QTextStream in(&htmlfile);
        htmlContent = in.readAll();

        QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument();
        document->setHtml(htmlContent);

        QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        printer.setOutputFileName(filepath+".pdf");

        document->print(&printer);
        delete document;
        buttonCancel();
    }
}

void MainWindow::buttonCancel()
{
    QApplication::quit();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to porting from QTWebKit to QTWebEngine which use Chromium as native browser, faster and newst. Check for details:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

With 5.6, Qt WebKit and Qt Quick 1 will no longer be supported and are dropped from the release. Qt 5.7 integrates printsupport for browser so let's try to use Chromium:

First of all, include:

```
QT       += webengine webenginewidgets printsupport
```

Now, try something like this:

```
// Create the webview
QWebEngineView *webView = new QWebEngineView(this);
webView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(webView);

// Path to the HTML file
const QString filePath =  QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Import HTML", ".", "HTML Files (*.html)");
// Check if the file exist
QFileInfo fileInfo(filePath);
if (!fileInfo.isFile()) {
    qDebug() << "Warning, file not found!";
}
// Preview the HTML file
webView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileInfo.filePath()));
// How to print the page?
// Get the path to the pdf file
const QString pdfPath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Export to pdf", ".", "PDF Files (*.pdf)");
// Print the page in pdf format
webView->page()->printToPdf(pdfPath);
```